# how to share syntax coloring preferences between projects in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, syntax, themes

I edited the syntax coloring in eclipse. When I changed the workspace, that preferences disappeared. Is there is a way to share the preferences of syntax coloring between workspaces?
I'm using darkest dark theme also.
I edited the syntax coloring preferences only for java and html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of the preferences are stored per workspace, so when you create a new workspace it will not have the customized preferences you set in the previous workspace. You might want to take a look at Oomph, maybe this article can help: https://eclipsesource.com/blogs/tutorials/oomph-basic-tutorial/ particularily about the "Preference Recorder".